# "retro"-look in 3d-XNA-game

Tags: xna, 3d, interpolation

In my XNA-4.0-game (which somehow is a bit like MineCraft), I have got some big cubes with small textures (16x16px) on it. By default, XNA just scales them up smooth so there aren't any hard borders. But as the game is a retro game, I want these big pixels.
So how do I turn of that interpolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the sampler state to Point clamp or wrap before drawing.

```
  GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;
```

Comment: If you program the shader yourself, you can do this in HLSL, too. This is done while defining a texture sampler. sampler2D ColorMapSampler = sampler_state
{
 Texture = <ColorMap>;
 MinFilter = linear;
 MagFilter = linear;
 MipFilter = linear;
 AddressU = Wrap;
 AddressV = Wrap;
};